# Ebean update modifies field with @CreateTimestamp annotation

Tags: playframework-2.1, ebean

I have an abstract class that all my persisted objects extends from, see below. The creationDate and modifiedDate fields are populated when the an object is initially saved, I can see the dates in the table. The issue I'm having is when I update the same object both creationDate and the modifiedDate are also updated, what I want is only the modifiedDate field to be updated.

I'm using play 2.1 with ebean.

The abstract class ...

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BasePersistableEntity extends Model  {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @CreatedTimestamp
    protected Date creationDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @UpdatedTimestamp
    @Version
    protected Date modifiedDate;

    public Date getCreationDate(){
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date date){
        creationDate = date;
    }

    public Date getModifiedDate(){
        return modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(Date date){
        modifiedDate = date;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Formats.DateTime(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
@CreatedTimestamp
@Column(updatable=false)
protected Date creationDate;
```

Just add the @Column(updatable=false) annotation to the creationDate field